# Possible memory leak when using a vector of a map of strings C++

Tags: c++, string, memory-leaks, dictionary, vector

I have a pretty complex data object that uses has a map of strings

```
typedef std::map<std::string, unsigned int> Event;
typedef std::pair<double, Event> EventGroup;
std::vector<EventGroup> eventVector;
```

This is a program that's always running in the background listening to incoming messages. Every time a new EventGroup comes in, which can have any number of strings in the map, I add it to the vector.

```
// New data came in
eventVector.push_back(newEventGroup);
```

Every now and then I'll do an erase on this vector

```
//Flush some of the data because it's old
// it's been determined that the index to erase at is flushIndex
eventVector.erase(eventVector.begin(), eventVector.begin()+flushIndex);
```

Typically this tends to be the first 5% of the data.

What I've been noticing is that there seems to be a memory leak. The memory usage starts out around 50 MB... but ends up near 1 GB before it's too slow and crashes. I've heard that it's an expensive operation to do an erase, but could this be the cause of the memory leak? Am I missing some way of freeing up the memory used by the map?

Comment: `erase()` will have to move memory around in your case, so it is a bit expensive, but it calls each element's destructor, so unless your classes are flawed in some way I can't imagine how you would have a leak in the code you have shown us.

Comment: what is the value of `eventVector.size()` through out? Is it increasing? How about `eventVector.capacity()`? How about the size of the individual maps it contains?

Comment: @awoodland: Good point.  OP, are you sure that you are stabalizing the size of your vector by erasing ~%5 every so often?  If you grow by 10% between each of your calls to erase() then you don't have a leak, but you will certainly chew up more and more memory over time.

Comment: Could you show your EventGroup definition? Maybe it contains dynamically allocated data that it does not deallocate upon destruction.

Comment: eventVector.size() stays roughly around 1500.  I delete the data based on the double in EventGroup since its a std::pair<double, Event> ... the double is sort of a time stamp, and the data comes in pretty deterministically. All of the guts of Event and EventGroup are pretty much what's posted, save an enum here or there.

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing what your custom types do or look like (are THEY leaking memory?) it's hard to say.  You should note however that erasing elements from a vector does not actually free any memory, it makes the area the vector has already allocated available for different elements added to THAT vector.  The vector's reserved space remains the same in other words.

So, if you grow a vector to some million elements, erase 90% of them, and are expecting to get a bunch of memory back you'll be disappointed.  The way you can free up memory reserved by a vector (which will NEVER give anything back until it's destroyed) is to do the swap idiom thing:

```
std::vector<EventGroup>(eventVector).swap(eventVector);
```

I don't recall the exact specifics of how the copy constructor works here.  It should behave exactly the same as if you'd done this:

```
std::vector<EventGroup>(eventVector.begin(), eventVector.end()).swap(eventVector);
```

You still have no control over how much space this uses up, but if you've freed a lot of space up and it will remain freed for a long while...this should give some unknown amount of memory back to the system.

Keep in mind that this is an expensive operation (which is why std::vector doesn't just do it for you) so only do it when you need to.

Comment: `eventVector.swap(std::vector<EventGroup>(eventVector));` won't compile because temporaries don't bind to non-const lvalue references. You want `std::vector<EventGroup>(eventVector).swap(eventVector);`. Also note that in C++11, there is `std::vector<>::shrink_to_fit()` to do this for you without extraneous copying.

Comment: I'll add that in C++11 you can simply do `vector.shrink_to_fit()`.

Comment: Good catch.  Didn't test it and I rarely do this.